# Bat renombra ficheros desde diferente directorio

Tags: batch, script

Tengo el siguiente script que funciona si lo ejecuto desde el mismo directorio:

```
@echo off
for %%i in (*.csv) do (set fname=%%~ni) & call :renameFile
goto :eof
:renameFile
ren "%fname%.csv" "%fname:~13,16%.csv"
goto :eof
```

Lo que pretendo es ejecutarlo desde otro directorio. Tengo un recurso compartido con varios directorios

```
- Orion (unidad de red)
  |-AEMET (directorio)
    |-Scripts (directorio)
    |-Temporal (directorio)
```

En `Temporal` tengo los ficheros que tengo que renombrar, pero para tenerlo todo mejor organizado me gustaría que el script se ejecutara desde el directorio `Scripts`.

Para ello he realizado la siguiente modificación pero no consigo que funcione.

```
@echo off
Set "Ficheros=\\AEMET\Temporal\*.csv"
for %%i in ("%Ficheros%") do (set fname=%%~ni) & call :renameFile
goto :eof
:renameFile
ren "%fname%.csv" "%fname:~13,16%.csv"
goto :eof
```

He probado:

- Quitando las barras de la unidad de red `AEMET\Temporal\`
- Llamándolo desde `\Temporal\`

Pero no consigo que funcione desde otro directorio.

¿Qué estoy haciendo mal?

Comment: Prueba de agregar el path hasta tu script en la variable de entorno path (echo %PATH% para ver su contenido) ejecutas en la consola SET PATH=%PATH%;c:\mis_scripts\batch\ asi cualquier cosa que pongas ahi la va a encontrar desde cualquier lado. En mi epoca esto se ponia en el autoexec.bat y ejecuta al iniciar la maquina. Eso se hacia hace 20 o 30 años.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Una posible solución sería ejecutar tu primer script, que funciona sin problemas, pero cambiando el directorio activo. Entonces lo que harías al principio sería cambiar el directorio activo a Temporal, buscar los ficheros, renombrarlos y volver al directorio de los Scripts:

```
@echo off
cd ..\Temporal
for %%i in (*.csv) do (set fname=%%~ni) & call :renameFile
goto :goBack
:renameFile
ren "%fname%.csv" "%fname:~13,16%.csv"
goto :eof
:goBack
cd ..\Scripts
```

---

Pero si quieres ir con tu segunda opción, te comento qué es lo que está mal y cómo corregirlo:

- En esta línea `Set "Ficheros=\\AEMET\Temporal\*.csv"` la ruta es incorrecta, Te sobra una `\` al principio (o agregar el nombre de red Orion) y por eso la ruta no conecta al lugar correcto y no encontrará ningún CSV (o no encontrará los que quieres).
- En el bucle `for` pierdes la ruta del fichero (que estaba en la variable Ficheros), pero ahora `i` sólo va a tener el nombre del archivo sin la ruta.
- Al usar `ren` poniendo sólo el nombre del archivo, sin ruta, se intentará renombrar los archivos CSV del directorio actual, no el Temporal.

Una idea sería cambiar `Ficheros` para que en lugar de la lista de los ficheros, contenga la ruta donde quieres cambiar los ficheros (moviendo la selección al mismo bucle `for`) y entonces usar `Ficheros` de nuevo en el `ren` (sólo en el primer argumento).

Entonces, este código ya te funcionará:

```
@echo off
Set "Ficheros=..\Temporal\"
for %%i in ("%Ficheros%*.csv") do (set fname=%%~ni) & call :renameFile
goto :eof
:renameFile
ren "%Ficheros%%fname%.csv" "%fname:~13,16%.csv"
goto :eof
```

Podrías cambiar la ruta de `Ficheros` para que sea absoluta en lugar de relativa y entonces el script te funcionará independientemente de dónde lo llames.

Comment: Gran idea, ha funcionado a la perfección. Muchas gracias Álvaro.

Comment: Gracias, @David. He agregado una edición explicando cómo podrías solucionar el script para que funcione con tu segunda opción. Es un cambio mínimo y creo que puede hacer el script más sólido (porque funcionaría sin importar desde dónde se llame)

Comment: Muchas gracias de nuevo Álvaro, con la segunda solución tengo justo lo que quería, que es ejecutar el bat desde otro directorio, y coincido contigo que es mejor opción que la primera, aún funcionando bien las dos. ¡Gracias! Por cierto no me di cuenta del detalle del ren al no poner la dirección :)